# CSS Background Linear Gradient from Top to Bottom

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a linear gradient from top to the bottom like:

[image: Gradient I want!]

Unfortunately what I get is:

[image: Gradient I get]

The following is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
        Hi
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
body{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, white, blue 80%) ;
}
```

If I do `90deg`, instead of `0deg` then I get this:

[image: Gradient with 90deg]

I need this gradient - but it should be rotated by 90deg i.e. from the top to the bottom instead of left to right. I'm curious why 0deg seems to give something similar to a repeated gradient.

I have used browsers, Firefox 21 and Chrome 27. I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Whats the calculated height of your body? Try setting CSS body to 100% height

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try setting the background on the `<html>` instead - may be easier to manage. Then give it a `height:100%;` as well so it for sure extends the whole page.

I also set it to `no-repeat` so you only get one gradient instead of it starting over at the bottom when you have longer content.

```
html{
    height:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, white, blue 80%) no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/nEQeZ/1/

**Edit**

fr13d pointed out in the comments, when putting the gradient on `html` the gradient will stop on the bottom of the first page, prior to any scrolling. That is, the gradient gets cut off when you scroll (noticeable if the background color is different than the gradient's lower color).

One way around this is to put the styling on `body` instead:

```
body{
    height:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, yellow, blue 80%) no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/nEQeZ/117/

Comment: A bit late, but it seems if your `<body>` contains enough content to extend past the bottom of the screen, once you scroll down, the new part that srcolls into view doesn't have the background anymore. (As the bottom part of your gradient is white, this will not matter in your case.)

Comment: Correct @DACrosby. Just to say it explicitly for any other seeking soul's benefit: If your gradient's lower color is not the default white, you could now set the  **`html`** `background-color` to your gradient's lower color. In this way the `body` blends until it reaches the `html` color, which goes further down all the way :-)

Comment: Additionally, you can use `min-height: 100%` and at least Chrome will extend it past.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the solution from @DACrosby, but recommend to extend the background with 'fixed'. In that case your background will stay in place and you will have the gradient for the whole site not just on the top.

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, red, blue 80%) fixed no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to give the `<body>` and `<html>` elements an explicit height as the former has none, nor any content:

http://jsfiddle.net/qL9mg/1/

Comment: Thanks **Adrift**. This seems to sort of work. If you do it without the `html` i.e. just the `body`, then it does not work. Why do you need both `body` and `html` specified?

Comment: Also, if you use the scroll bar to scroll to the bottom, it has a dark blue line. Can we avoid that?

Comment: @O.O: Because the `<body>` doesn't know what 100% height is *referring* to, as the percentage value is always relative to another value, e.g. the height of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, white, blue 80%) ;
}

body {
    height: 0%;
}
```